# Migrating to Openshift Online Stuck

Tags: migration, openshift, openshift-3

I'm migrating my podcast site, but build is pending for more than an hour.

```
oc get events                                                 19:09:02

LASTSEEN   FIRSTSEEN   COUNT     NAME                     KIND          SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON                         SOURCE                                                 MESSAGE
50m        50m         1         opendevpodcast-1-build   Pod                       Normal    Scheduled                      default-scheduler                                      Successfully assigned opendevpodcast-1-build to ip-172-31-61-152.us-west-2.compute.internal
1m         48m         7         opendevpodcast-1-build   Pod                       Warning   FailedSync                     kubelet, ip-172-31-61-152.us-west-2.compute.internal   Error syncing pod
9m         47m         6         opendevpodcast-1-build   Pod                       Normal    SandboxChanged                 kubelet, ip-172-31-61-152.us-west-2.compute.internal   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
50m        50m         1         opendevpodcast           BuildConfig               Warning   BuildConfigInstantiateFailed   buildconfig-controller                                 gave up on Build for BuildConfig opendev/opendevpodcast (0) due to fatal error: the LastVersion(1) on build config opendev/opendevpodcast does not match the build request LastVersion(0)
```

I check the https://status.starter.openshift.com/ and is says:

> starter-us-west-2 experiencing elevated level of app create errors
>
> Investigating - We're experiencing an elevated level of app create
>   errors and are currently looking into the issue.  Sep 30, 17:32 EDT

Comment: Why has a bounty been added to this. @jack-flamp, if you are having an issue of your own, you are better off creating a new question describing the specifics of your problem rather than putting a bounty a question from a different user, as it may not be the same issue.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yeah you may be right. I am just frustratred that openshift makes me change platform and then it doesn't work on the new and I can't figure out why. I can't remove the bounty. ends in 7 days

Comment: The problem is that can't be sure you problem is the same and you don't provide a description to work from. You could be getting hit by the current stability issues with new app/route creation and re-deployments. You might be hitting resource limits. You might not have switched to Recreate deployment strategy instead of Rolling if you are at memory limit. Too many unknowns and why a separate question with details is better.